# Identify Font File Used in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2010

I know that the font files used by Microsoft Word is located at

> C:\Windows\Fonts

I am particularly concern about the font `OCR A Std`. I want to locate the font files for the `OCR A Std` `regular` font, `bold` font, `italic` font and `bold italic` font. Below are the sample fonts:

> [image]
>
> Regular
>
> [image]
>
> Bold
>
> [image]
>
> Italics
>
> [image]
>
> Bold Italics

Now, I want to locate the four corresponding font files for the said font. But when, I look at `C:\Windows\Fonts`, only `2` font file with the name `OCRAStd.otf (OCR A Std Regular)` and `OCRAEXT.TTF (OCR A Extended)` is found. Unlike with other fonts like Times New Roman,its corresponding four font versions are found, namely: `Times New Roman Regular`, `Times New Roman Bold`, `Times New Roman Italics` and `Times New Roman Bold Italics`. My questions are :

1. Is `C:\Windows\Fonts`, the right location where I can find the font files for `Microsoft Word 2010`? If no, then where? If yes, what are the font file names corresponding to the four versions of `OCR A`? How can I determine it by myself?
2. If it is not in my computer, where can I download it? I already searched the web but only found `OCR-A Std Regular` and `Bold`, no `Italics` and `Bold Italics`.

Comment: Go to \Windows\Fonts and doubleclick ocrastd.otf ... OTF files can contain multiple fonts.  When you doubleclick, you'll see them, if they're included.

Comment: Windows will transform a normal font to bold/italic even if those specific fonts don't exist. This is what a program fills in to get Windows to create a font https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfonta. Remember fonts are described mathematically with hinting and/or bitmaps for smaller sizes.